# Notepad++ Как поменять слова местами в каждой строке?

Tags: регулярные-выражения, notepad++

Есть много строк в текстовом файле.

Например:

```
hi.    привет.
we.    мы.
how?   как?
hello. привет.
```

Разделение между словами в каждой строке - TAB.
Нужно поменять слова местами в каждой строке так что бы получилось:

```
привет.    hi.
мы.    we.
как?    how?
....
.... и тд
```

Есть ли такая возможность в Np++?

Comment: Это разовая операция? Я бы задачу разделил на 2 части: Создал бы 2 листа, где только русский и только английский текст, воспользовавшись заменой совпадений через регулярные выражение на пустую строку. Далее, все это скопировал в 2 столбца экселя, а потом копипстнул бы назад.

Comment: @iluxa1810 *"через регулярные выражение"* - месье знает толк

Comment: @VTT Да ладно... Если 1 раз нужно сделать, то норм.

Comment: Можно попробовать. Спасибо!) Но хочется конечно иметь решение в виде регулярного выражения. Было бы очень круто!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

жмем `Ctrl+H` Делаем Найти `(.*?)[\t](.*)` и Заменить `$2\t$1`, ставим галку *Регулярные выражения* и *Заменить все*

Comment: Опоздали на 25 сек=)

Comment: @iluxa1810 выделял курсивом долго :D

Comment: Это решение сработало! Спасибо!

Comment: @GaloGramma тыкайте галку у ответа тогда

Answer (score 2):

1. Включаете регулярные выражения
2. Пишете ~ такую регулярку `(?i)([a-z]+.)\s([а-я]+.)`
3. В замене пишете это `\2 \1`

Вуаля

Comment: Это решение сработало! Спасибо! ..но 2 галочки не поставить(

Comment: @GaloGramma Эх, а я был первее.=( Хотя бы + поставьте.

Comment: Что за хейтер регулярных выражений поставил минус?